# How to get the url from a input field?

Tags: addthis

I recently develop a shortener URL script, now I'm trying to add Addthis buttons but the problem is that is sharing the current URL of the site is on. I want the Addthis buttons share the URL that is inside of the URL Input field anybody got some idea on how to do it?

Basically I want to add Addthis buttons and share the URL from a Input field that got the URL shorted .

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, and share what have you been trying so far.

Comment: Basically I want to add Addthis buttons and share the URL that is return from database and it show in the input field that got the URL shorted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Real Question: How can you specify a custom URL for Addthis?

**jQuery Solution**

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" class="addthis_button" id="youmusthaveanid">
```

jQuery

```
$('#youridhere').attr('addthis:url', $('#yourinput').val);
```

Note: Remember you will have to trigger this on every update of the text box if it's content changes after the Javascript has been run on initial load.
**PHP Solution**

HTML/PHP

```
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php" class="addthis_button" addthis:url="<?=$yourvariablehere?>"
```

---

Source: [Addthis API Docs](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#.Ug1vQWRVqFc)